# Can I Specify Title Page Customization in a Template Instead of My Document?

Tags: beamer, titles, backgrounds

I'm trying to create a LaTeX `beamer` theme to match the official PowerPoint template of Rutgers University.  I've been able to create the title page, and this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetheme{NewBrunswick}

    \title{This Is A Long Descriptive Title Describing How Much Easier It Would Be To 
        Study \LaTeX{} And Not Hypersonics}
    \author{Someone Other Than Till Tantau}
    \institute[MAE]{Fake Degree Candidate \and Mechanical \& Aerospace Engineering}
    \date{A Long, Long, Time Ago}

\begin{document}
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{rutgersTitle} }
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} }
\end{document}
```

with this MWE `beamerthemeNewBrunswick.sty` file

```
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{3\baselineskip}}{}
```

resembles it:

[image: sampleTitlePage]

Is there a way for me to take the background image code out of the document, and into a/the theme file?  I would like to distribute this so users can just specify

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

and get the background image that I've stored with the theme files.  I tried adding this to the theme file

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{}{
    \usebackgroundtemplate{
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{rutgersTitle} } }
```

but it doesn't add the background image as I had hoped.

**EDIT:**

Trying `textpos` with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetheme{NewBrunswick}

    \title{This Is A Long Descriptive Title Describing How Much Easier It Would Be To
        Study \LaTeX{} And Not Hypersonics}
    \author{Someone Other Than Till Tantau}
    \institute[MAE]{Fake Degree Candidate \and
                    Mechanical \& Aerospace Engineering}
    \date{A Long, Long, Time Ago}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

where `beamerthemeNewBrunswick.sty` now contains

```
\RequirePackage{textpos}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{3\baselineskip}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(-2.6em, -1.6em)
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{rutgersTitle}
    \end{textblock*} }{}
```

produces
[image: newSample]
where you can see there's an additional white bar on the bottom.  Did I use `textpos` incorrectly?  Here is my background image:
[image: backgroundImage]
I guess I should be adding to the question instead of comments.  Is `textpos` using a centering-like effect here?  If I add something like

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{10\baselineskip}}{}
```

the background image moves up the slide and my text moves down the slide.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**
Using Tikz appeared to be the only way to avoid hard coding sizes, so I went with it despite increased compile time.  My final code for the `.sty` file was:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{3\baselineskip}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.center) {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{rutgersTitle}
        };
        \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (0.04\paperwidth,-0.01\paperheight) {
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{tigre}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
```

Comment: @diabonas similar question, but duplicate?  i'm trying to use different commands that have a different level of nesting.  i also wouldn't call that resolution adequate, as it isn't tied to `\titlepage` at all. the title page might not, in theory, be on the first slide.  or if i'm not using a title page, my first slide shouldn't have the background image.

Comment: Your're right, I'm sorry I missed that difference.

Comment: @asia1281: I think the white bar is due to the `plain` option. Use simply `\begin{frame}\titlepage\end{frame}`; if this doesn't solve the problem, please upload the  image file rutgersTitle somewhere, so I can do some tests.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina i tried it without the `plain` option, and it still has the strange white bar at the bottom.  i do need the `plain` option though, as this will need to work in presentations that have a footer defined.  currently, this is how i'm keeping the footer off of the title page and questions page et cetera.

Comment: @asia1281:I'll do some tests and get back to you.

Comment: @asia1281: where do the black bars come from? The image you just posted doesn't have black bars. Are you doing anything different in your theme to produce those bars? With the image you just left I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina oh, sorry, the black bars are just from my taking a screenshot of the title page while in presentation mode.  they're not actually there.  the white bar, however, does appear as a part of my slide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this `beamerthemeNewBrunswick.sty` file; the idea is to use the [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package to add the background image at an absolute position; of course, using several nodes you can add several images; for example, defining `beamerthemeNewBrunswick.sty` in the following way:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{3\baselineskip}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
  \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{rutgersTitle}};             
  \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (1cm,-0.7\paperheight)
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{tigre}};             
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{}


\RequirePackage{textpos}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(-2.6em,-1.6em)
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{tigre} 
\end{textblock*}%
\begin{textblock*}{2cm}(0cm,6cm)
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tigre} 
\end{textblock*}
}{}
```

and using the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{NewBrunswick}

\title{This Is A Long Descriptive Title Describing How Much Easier It Would Be To
        Study \LaTeX{} And Not Hypersonics}
\author{Someone Other Than Till Tantau}
\institute[MAE]{Fake Degree Candidate \and
                    Mechanical \& Aerospace Engineering}
\date{A Long, Long, Time Ago}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

you'll get

[image]

Comment: while i don't have any `textpos` experience, if this works it creates another problem.  this is actually the first step in a two step process, and i had planned to use `textpos` or `tikz` to stick another image on top of (overlay) the background image for the template.  would `textpos` be able to handle adding both images to the template?

Comment: @asia1281: yes; I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: oh sweet.  i think it's funny that so many beamer examples have a tiger in them!

Comment: i was able to fix it by changing `-1.6em` to `-1.15em`.  is it really not capable of filling the slide or at least using variables to position it just right?  those numbers just seem kind of arbitrary to me.

Comment: fyi, it looks to be image dependent.  i just tried it with another background image and i needed to use `-1.55em` to eliminate white space.

Comment: it also looks to be dependent upon what is on the title page, which could end up being a problem.  the new background image moved when i overlaid a second small image on top of it like you showed.  if i use `\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\vspace{4\baselineskip}}{}` it moves again, but in the opposite direction.  does it use a centering-like effect?

Comment: @asia1281: I've changed from `textpos` to `tikz`; process the example code at least three times to get the correct positioning.